# C-lightning configuration to use bitcoin blockchain data from another machine

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, core-lightning

I currently run a lightning node on umbrel on a raspberry pi. I want to experiment with c-lightning and want to run a new c-lightning node on my ubuntu laptop which utilizes the blockchain data from my existing umbrel node.

Which files do I need to configure for that and in doing that do I reduce my umbrel node's security in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following in your conf file and have Bitcoin Core installed on your Ubuntu machine too.

```
bitcoin-rpcuser=foo
bitcoin-rpcpassword=foo
bitcoin-rpcurl=http://127.0.0.1:18332
```

Core Lightning will use the bitcoin-cli to make a connection with your bitcoind on the other machine!